PyQt6 failure in Python 3.13.0 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named PyQt6.sip
The following simple example fails at line 2, the import, when run with Python 3.13.0 and PyQt6 6.7.1 in October of 2024:
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()
w.resize(250, 200)
w.setWindowTitle('HelloWorld')
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())

The error:
"C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" c:\projects\python\PyQtSimpleExample\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\python\PyQtSimpleExample\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6.sip'***

The temporary work-around is to stop using PyQt6 6.7.1 and switch to PySide6 6.7.3 which does not suffer from the same issue.

I was going to suggest you to uninstall and reinstall again, but I see that you did that (at least indirectly). Note that answers should not be added to questions. If you found that in a PyQt related StackOverflow post, then consider this as a duplicate (possibly not reproducible) and you should eventually flag it as such on your own by also adding the link. If not, and assuming that this is indeed reproducible in some way, then add an appropriate answer instead.

My fix/solution was not so much a "duplicate" as it was a "similar but different", meaning things like the use of --force-reinstall were the same as my research suggested, but the set of packages involved was completely different.

In any case, questions cannot contain answers. Either find an appropriate duplicate, or eventually use the "answer your question" button.

pip install PyQt6 sip --force-reinstall
My fix/solution was not so much a "duplicate" as it was a "similar but different", meaning things like the use of --force-reinstall were the same as my research suggested, but the set of packages involved was completely different
